# "WC()->cart->get_subtotal()" returns 0 when using "woocommerce_product_get_tax_class" hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, tax

I'm trying to drop the VAT on my cart items when the subtotal is over a specific amount. But when I use `WC()->cart->get_subtotal()` to get the subtotal price, it returns 0 and my if statement fails.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wp_check_uk_vat', 1, 2 );
    
function wp_check_uk_vat( $tax_class, $product ) {

    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    // echo $cart_total;

    if( $cart_total >= 100 ) {

        $tax_class = "Zero rate";

    }

    return $tax_class;

}
```

Similar code is used here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/#section-18

The goal of the code is to drop the VAT on the cart (not shipping) when the order amount is over 135 GBP (to comply with the new Brexit rules for merchants).

Because `WC()->cart->get_subtotal()` returns 0, the if statement fails, and the VAT is not being dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wp_check_uk_vat', 1, 2 );

function wp_check_uk_vat( $tax_class, $product ) {

    if(WC()->cart){
    $subtotal = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item[ 'data' ]->get_price( 'edit' ) * $cart_item[ 'quantity' ];
    }

    if ( $subtotal >= 100 ) {

        $tax_class = "Zero rate";
    }
    }
    return $tax_class;
}
```

Comment: Does this also work with variable products ? If I use woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class ?

Comment: Though I am late here, but the woocommerce doc still has code returning subtotal 0 code.
Thanks @mujuony for the above answer. upvoted.